# Grammatical meaning of に-particle in へいわに

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-に

I'm aware that the に-particle has a lot of different grammatical meanings. The most common of these are time, place and indirect object.

But I came across the following sentence and I can't really make up what the grammatical meaning of the particle is here.

"人間は　平和に　暮らしている。" --"The people live in peace."

Could someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[平和]{へいわ} = peace

平和な = peaceful

平和に = peacefully

The に makes the word function adverbially to modify a verb (in this case, [暮]{く}らしている).